# Discontinuous Solver Constraint Workaround

Tags: excel, excel-formula, constraints, excel-2010, solver

I am developing a production simulation using OpenSolver in Excel. I know that I cannot use if, or, and statements to constrain a solver.

I need a constraint that says:

X has to be within the range of 150 - 250, or X can equal 0.

I have read about different ways to substitute binary constraints for conditional formulas, but I am not sure how to make it work exactly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
150 d <= x <= 250 d 
d in {0,1}
```

or make `x` a semi-continuous variable with lower bound 150 and upper bound 250. I am not sure but I believe OpenSolver does not support semi-continuous variables so you need to use the first formulation using an extra binary variable.

Comment: I have tried this using a single binary variable d as you explained, and I get an error message that says Open Solver cannot find a feasible solution. 

Can you explain what you mean by using an extra binary variable in the  first formulation?

Comment: `x semi-continuous between [150,250]` uses zero extra binary variables while `150 d <= x <= 250 d` uses one extra binary variable.

Comment: Using the constraint 150d <= x <= 250d, where x and d are both decision variables & d is binary.  I am getting an error message saying there is no feasible solution and it does not appear to allow x to run over 150

Comment: So, the model is likely to be infeasible.

Comment: Any idea what some common causes are that make the model  infeasible? Does this type of constraint normally work in a solver? 

Perhaps there are other reasons my solver is infeasible.

Comment: Most common causes are errors in the model or the data.